# Hierarchy relationship in nosql

Tags: mongodb, nosql, data-modeling

```
course
  lesson
    activity
```

About three *activities* create one *lesson* and about 16 *lessons* make up the *course*.

I want to separate the *activity* and *lesson* documents. (to make *lessons* and *courses* by selecting them)

Each document has a CRUD operation, and *lesson* and *activity* appear when outputting *course* information.

Which is better for reference and inclusion in nosql?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding your question, but there is no problem with creating seperate collections for each type of record (activity, lesson and course) and then simply referencing the id of the required lessons and activities as required.  This would give you the appearance of a hierarchy.

For example you may have something like below for a course

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ev"
  },
  "course_name": "Course 1",
  "lessons": [
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ew"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ex"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ey"
    },
  ]
}
```

and this for a lesson

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ev"
  },
  "lesson_name": "Lesson 1",
  "activity": [
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ez"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ea"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206eb"
    },
  ]
}
```

If you know the kind of details you would like to display and wish to minimise queries, there is no problem with including some of the detail more than one of the collections, example below for courses

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ev"
  },
  "course_name": "Course 1",
  "lessons": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ew"
      },
      "lesson_name": "Lesson 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ex"
      },
      "lesson_name": "Lesson 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bbf5d8e1ed05050136206ey"
      },
      "lesson_name": "Lesson 3"
    },
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.